# Use LINQ to compare items in a list

Tags: linq

I have the following items (being displayed on UI)

```
Items       | Type          |   Providers       |

Choclate    | Mint          |   Nestle          |
Choclate    | BlueBerry     |   Nestle          |
Choclate    | White         |   Nestle          |
Choclate    | Mint          |   LocalProvider   |
Choclate    | BlueBerry     |   LocalProvider   |
Choclate    | White         |   LocalProvider   |
Starburst   | mixed         |   SomeXProvider   |
SourPatch   | mixed         |   SomeYProvider   |
Toffee      | Carmel        |   LocalProvider   |
Toffee      | Salted Carmel |   NewProvider     |
Toffee      | Vanilla       |   Eclairs         |
```

I am trying to get *Items* that have multiple *Providers* but not the others ones. How can I structure my LINQ query to get the result. I have been looking online for a while but have not found anything.

eg, Choclate has multiple providers. I want to get a list that has only Chocalte so that I can filter it the way I want.

I want to remove Local Provider from the list as I have Nestle as the provider.

My end result is should look like

```
Items       | Type          |   Providers       |

Choclate    | Mint          |   Nestle          |
Choclate    | BlueBerry     |   Nestle          |
Choclate    | White         |   Nestle          |
Starburst   | mixed         |   SomeXProvider   |
SourPatch   | mixed         |   SomeYProvider   |
Toffee      | Salted Carmel |   NewProvider     |
Toffee      | Vanilla       |   Eclairs         |
```

A user helped me a little bit but the result was not as expected. Updated Query

```
responses.GroupBy(x => x.Items).Where(g => g.Select(y => y.Providers != "LocalProvider").Distinct().Count() > 1).Select(b => b.First());
```

Comment: Is this correct: you want to keep all Items except those that have multiple (distinct) Providers, one of which is `LocalProvider`? And does the Type matter in any way?

Comment: @PeterB. Yes, I want to keep all items  but if an item has multiple provider, I want to keep the one with Nestle and delete LocalProvider. The Type does not matter

Comment: If we add this 1 row "Choclate | mixed | LocalProvider" to the input list, should it be removed or kept? (Because there is no row "Choclate | mixed | Nestle" )

Comment: @PeterB, we should keep that row. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @PeterB, any suggestions on how I can achieve it? Have been working on it for a while with no luck. The answer helped me a little bit but not fully. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it in three smaller steps to make it clear what is happening. You could combine this into one big statement, but that might make it less clear.

```
// Gather all the Local products
var localProducts = products.Where(x => x.Providers == "LocalProvider");

// Find Local products that have a non-local counterpart
var localProductsToRemove = localProducts.Where(
    x => products.Any(
        y => y.Items == x.Items && y.Type == x.Type && y.Providers != x.Providers
    )
);

// Take all products except the ones that we want to remove
var result = products.Except(localProductsToRemove);
```

Runnable .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RePXLY

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. I should have broken the query down rather than trying to finish it in one go. THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH !!!!!.

Answer (score 1):

```
var secondList = responses.Where(x => x.Providers != "LocalProvider").GroupBy(x => x.Items).ToList();
```

Cast your results into another variable. That variable will then contain the filtered results.

Comment: What would you be selecting in this case? IF i do SelectMany(x => x) this would yield me items which have multiple provider but I also want to get the items that dont have multiple providers.

Comment: This selects all items that do not have a provider equal to "Local Provider". The result set will be the same as you've posted

Comment: I get an error saying `Cannot implicity convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<string, myproject>> to System.Collections.Generic.List<myproject>`
The return type is ABC<IEnumerable<MyClass>>

So I am unable to assign it to another variable. I am returning the response list. Any ideas around that? Thanks alot

Comment: George, I think I had my table setup wrong. Your query would return the correct result. I have updated the table for the data I want. can you suggest what I can do to get the same result? Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. If you want to filter the list to get the result set as you have listed it in your question, then use the line of code I provided